# Use Cell Value Reference in VBA to determine range

Tags: vba, excel, reference, range

I know this is a pretty basic question, but im still working on building my VBA skills. I am in a predicament where I have made a mapping system of various reports I receive that get placed in a compiled workbook. These reports have entirely different formats etc. I have a copy/paste macro that copies columns and places them in their correct position on the compiled workbook.

I've come into situations however where there are a lot of duplicate / empty rows that screw up my Macro. I have used two VBA functions to solve this, one is a "delete row if reference column is blank":

```
Sub DeleteBlankARows()
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Long
    For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 6) = "" Then Rows(r).Delete
    Next r
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With End Sub
```

This deletes rows where cells in column F are empty

I also use a copy/paste down macro:

```
Sub CopyUntilBlank()
Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Range("f1").End(xlDown).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("d2:d" & last_row)

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    cell.Activate
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next cell End Sub
```

This copies and pastes down blank rows in column D until you hit a non-blank cell then re-does this until the range of values in column F.

These macros work well for me, but because I have multiple sheets like this, I would like to create a cell references that make the ranges dynamic. For instance: in the DeleteBlankRows macro, I would like to have the column reference in Cells(r,6) be determined off of a cell value in sheet1 - so for instance if the value in cell A1 on sheet 1 is 2 it would change the column reference to "2" (column B).

I would like the same to happen for the copy/paste down macro. I'm pretty sure this is just some reference to A1.Value but I don't know how to properly write such thing.

Thank you for your support, I've gone quite a long way with all the support of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example using your first sub:

```
Sub DeleteBlankARows(colIndex as Long)
Dim colIndex as long
colIndex = Sheet1.Range("a1").value
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Long
    For r = Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, colIndex) = "" Then Rows(r).Delete
    Next r
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With 
End Sub
```

It's not clear from your question which column in the second sub needs to be dynamic (or both of them?)

**EDIT** try this:

```
Sub CopyUntilBlank()
    Dim last_row As Long, col1 as Long, col2 as Long
    Dim rng as Range

    col1 = Sheet1.Range("a2").value
    col2 = Sheet1.Range("a3").value

    last_row = Cells(1, col1).End(xlDown).Row
    'This next line is better if there's any chance
    '  of blanks in this column
    'last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col2), .Cells(last_row, col2)) 
    End With

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
      If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
      End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't add specifics for the second sub because once i know the methodology/syntax for making the reference I can hopefully figure the rest out :).. Thank you kindly! I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: FYI - in your second sub you can remove the `cell.Activate` line and then just use `cell` wherever you have `ActiveCell`.  There's seldom any need to activate or select ranges when working with VBA.

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually struggling with implimenting the change on the second sub (worked perfectly for the first). I want it too to be dynamic, in this case I have a cell reference to the last_row "Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row" and another for "rng=Range("d2:d" & last_row)"

Comment: excellent!!!! I liked your suggestion as well for the change of having blank cells within the column. tested and it worked FANTASTICALLY! Thanks again!